# Which model I have to pass to view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

### The goal

Work with a model in my view.

### The problem

I'm getting the follow exception:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[MyApp.Models.Data.bm_product_categories,<>f__AnonymousType3`1[System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyApp.Models.Data.bm_product_categories]'.

### Details

I'm using:

- C#.Net
- Razor Engine
- MVC 4
- Visual Studio 2012

My *partial* view (**_CategoriesList**):

```
@model IEnumerable<BluMercados.Models.Data.bm_product_categories>

<h1>Testing</h1>
```

My controller (**CategoriesController**) and his method:

```
public ActionResult Render()
{
    var sluggifiedProjection =
        db.bm_product_categories
        .ToList()
        .Select(category => new
        {
            CategoryNameSlugged = category.Category_Name.GenerateSlug()
        });

    return PartialView("_CategoriesList", sluggifiedProjection);
}
```

### The question

How can I fix this problem? I really do not know what is the model that I have to pass from controller to view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are passing an anonymous type as part of the model.  While you can do this with the dynamic keyword,  you are probably better off making a ViewModel.

Something like

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public WhatEverTypeThisIs NameSlugged { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
public ActionResult Render()
{
    var sluggifiedProjection =
        db.bm_product_categories
        .ToList()
        .Select(category => new CategoryViewModel
        {
            NameSlugged = category.Category_Name.GenerateSlug()
        });

    return PartialView("_CategoriesList", sluggifiedProjection);
}
```

and the model will be something like

```
 @model IEnumerable<BluMercados.ViewModels.CategoryViewModel>
```

depending what namespace you put it in

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the select where you currently create instances of an anonymous type with a single property CategoryNameSlugged. You should make sure that your select operation does not change the type of the enumerable. This might work out if the property can be set:

```
.Select(category =>
        {
            category.CategoryNameSlugged = category.Category_Name.GenerateSlug();
            return category;

        });
```

Comment: `category doesn't contain a definition for CategoryNameSlugged.` is what Visual Studio returns to me. `CategoryNameSlugged` isn't defined previously. I am creating it now because is being necessary.